# Accessing the whole state object in React 16.8

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As react 16.8 introduced react hooks, accessing and setting the state have been changed. Previously you have access to whole state object with `{this.state}`, now since you directly access your state like `{count}` vs `{this.state.count}` I could not find a way to access whole state object. Is it possible the retrieve the whole state object in the new way of writing react component?

To be more clear; I have a React Component which takes the component state as props and displays it in UI for debugging purposes. I know I can use react plugin but i find it more efficient to display the state in UI as I code.

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

function App() {

  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: RectangularSelectProps) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        expanded: false,
        otherStuff: {
          string: 'bla bla'
        }
      };
    }
    render() {
      return ( < React.Fragment >
        Component:
        <div> *** Component Code ** * </div>
        Debug:
        <div style = {{margin: '1rem 0'}} >
        <h3 style = {{fontFamily: 'monospace'}}/> <pre style = {
          {
            background: '#f6f8fa',
            fontSize: '.65rem',
            padding: '.5rem',
          }
        } > {
          JSON.stringify({ ...this.state
          }, null, 2)
        } </pre> </div> </React.Fragment>)
      }
    }

    return ( < div > < MyComponent / > < /div>);
  }

  ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The simple answer to your question is that with React hooks and `useState` there is no single "state object." There are as many or as state few values as you declare. More significantly, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I've add what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike state in a class component, which would hold state as an object, there is no restriction of the state type with `useState` hook. It can take the state as a `string, boolean, number, object or array`. The only caveat is that setState would merge the updated state object with the previous state whereas hooks setter doesn't do that. You can also have **multiple useState declarations** with multiple different state types within a component

Example of using `useState` hooks would be

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [name, setName] = useState('Mr A');
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: 'Mr B', email: 'mrb@xyz.com'});
const [items, setItems] = useState(['Foo', 'Bar']);
```

Each usage of `useState` will have its own reference and return the state and its setter.

The setter to `useState` is passed with the new value of state. It may also take a callback function which is passed the previous value of state

Example

```
setUser({name: 'Mr C', email: 'mrc@xyz.com'});
```

or

```
setUser(prevState => ({...prevState, email:'mrB12@pwd.com'}))
```

**DEMO**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ name: "A", email: "ABC@PWD.com" });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, name: 'B' }))}>
        {state.name}
      </div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
        Click To increment count
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

P.S. In most cases `useState` will work for you. However if your state gets complex and need complex mutation `useReducer` is the best way forward. You can have a look at the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to have something similar to `this.state` if you really need some complex structure.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way of accessing the whole state if you split it up into several `useState` hooks, but you can still use one `useState` hook with an object that you use as state to get it all in one place.

Updating the state with hooks will however replace the entire existing state, so with this approach you need to merge it with the existing state object.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState({ ...state, foo: Math.random() })}>
        {state.foo}
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setState({ ...state, bar: Math.random() })}>
        {state.bar}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```